# How to cache query result Symfony2+MongoDB (ODM)

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.3, doctrine-odm

I want to cache query result as my query is too heavy, it takes approx 2 - 5 minutes to execute, but Symfony2 + MongoDB do not support it currently according to it.

[Doctrine MongoDB result caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473797/doctrine-mongodb-result-caching)

And I did not find anything after searching lots of in google for the same no any documents is there for the same.

Anybody have any idea how to achieve it with Symfony2+MongoDB

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks advance

Comment: Cache it by yourself. Or instead of [ranting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473797/doctrine-mongodb-result-caching#comment80393238_12500748) implement the caching and send a PR to ODM.

Comment: is there any reference where I can get bit information regarding it.(caching and send a PR to ODM)

Comment: I assume the best would be to mimic what ORM does with result cache or 2nd level cache. Here are two issues I found with some discussions: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/653 and https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1490